# Mute microphone from a Windows Runtime Component, and consume it from a Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

My issue is that I have to develop a Runtime Component in Visual C++, to mute/unmute the device speaker, and then import that component into a Windows Phone 8 app (in C#) to use it.

## 1st step

So, first of all I have a method to get the status of the microphone, the API for Runtime Components says that to retrieve the AudioDeviceController, which represents the microphone, first you need to capture the devices with MediaCapture class.

**Runtime Component:**

*AudioManager.cpp*

```
bool DeviceManagerWrapper::getMicrophoneMutedStatus(){
    MediaCapture^ media = ref new Windows::Media::Capture::MediaCapture();

    AudioDeviceController^ audioDevice = media->AudioDeviceController;
    return audioDevice->Muted;
}
```

**Call from WP8 app:**

```
...
var wrapper = new DeviceManagerWrapper.AudioManager();
var res = wrapper.getMicrophoneMutedStatus();
Debug.WriteLine("Microphone muted? "+ res);
```

But after debugging it results in stopping when wrapper makes the call to get the status of the microphone, retrieving the error:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Joe.App.WindowsPhone.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: This object needs to be initialized before the
>   requested operation can be carried out.
>
> Additional information: This object needs to be initialized before the
>   requested operation can be carried out.
>
> This object needs to be initialized before the requested operation can
>   be carried out.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

## 2nd step

In that case I try to initialize according to the documentation the MediaCapture object:

```
bool DeviceManagerWrapper::getMicrophoneMutedStatus(){
    MediaCapture^ media = ref new Windows::Media::Capture::MediaCapture();
    create_task(media->InitializeAsync()).wait();

    AudioDeviceController^ audioDevice = media->AudioDeviceController;
    return audioDevice->Muted;
}
```

and in the WP8 app we wait for the task be finished:

```
...
ThreadPool.RunAsync(x => {
    bool res = wrapper.getMicrophoneStatus();
    Debug.WriteLine("Microphone muted? "+ res);
});
```

But even with this, I get an error which reads as follow:

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>   Joe.App.WindowsPhone.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Access is denied.
>
> Additional information: Access is denied.
>
> Access is denied.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

Any help is welcomed !!!

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh768223.aspx, in particular: “The first call to start using a sensitive device must be made on the main UI thread so the consent prompt can be shown to the user.” Not sure if it applies here but worth trying.

Comment: have you added the required capabilities in the manifest file?